# Building a data driven Dashboard in Django along with pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas, web, dashboard

Problem statement - what am trying to do is create a dashboard using Django and pandas. Pandas will do the calculation part and Django would be displaying the data and all plots and graphs.

Achieved: Created an app and imported pandas in the views file. and then rendering it. though getting my data on display but its the error screen with my data. what I understood is I have to use a template to show my data.

my code:

```
def index(request):
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("C:/Users/lol/Desktop/lol.csv"))
    dff = df[["column_one", "column_two", "column_three"]]
    dff = dff.set_index("column_one")
    return render(request, dff.head(5))
```

If someone can point me how to push the data frame to the website in a tabular format.
Current HTML format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello Hi </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, am new to Django.

Comment: How do you want to display your data? Tables or charts and graphs?

Comment: To start with Tables would be enough, but going forward charts would be demanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframes in pandas have to_html method that can be used to get html string. You can pass this string from your view in a variable and then in template you can just access it like a simple variable. For example your return statement from view can be like

```
return render(request, template_name, context={'data': dataframe.to_html()})
```

Then in your template you can simply use `{{ data|safe }}` to print it out.

For reference, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank You for the solution just another challenge - its not displaying in tabular format though its coming something like this                                 <table border="1" class="dataframe"> <thead> <tr style="text-align: right;"> <th></th> <th>column_one</th> <th>column_two</th> <th>column_three</th> <th>coloumn_four</th> <th>column_five</th> <th>column_six</th>

Comment: There is not to see, provide a link to image/snapshot of it.

Comment: <table border="1" class="dataframe"> <thead> <tr style="text-align: right;"> <th></th> <th>column_one</th> <th>column_two</th> <th>column_three</th> <th>coloumn_four</th> <th>column_five</th> <th>column_six</th>

Comment: Oh, just type {{ data|safe }}, it will then render as html.